# Sox doesn't work with Cron

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, cron

I'm trying to use Cron to play an MP3 file at a set time (This is more or less a POC alarm clock). Basically, I have my `crontab` file set up to run a bash script as follows:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && export XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority && home/username/test
```

Here is the bash file that is supposed to play the audio file; I'm using play from `sox`.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin
play /home/username/Media/Music/my_audio.mp3
```

If I run the file by itself, it works just fine, but nothing happens whatsoever when with `cron`. Can someone please give me some pointers as to what I need to fix? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`cron` is not `bash` (and your `bash` syntax is wrong, too. Read `man bash`). Read `man 5 crontab`, and, to achive what you seem to want:

In your `crontab` (`crontab -e`)

```
DISPLAY=:0 
XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority
* * * * *  /home/username/test
```

BUT! This is not necessary! the `play` command uses neither `$DISPLAY` or `$XAUTHORITY`.

From `man play`:

```
SoX is a command-line audio processing tool, particularly suited to making quick, simple edits and to batch processing.  If
you need an interactive, graphical audio editor, use audacity(1).
```

Your problem is that `cron`s `$PATH` is not the same as yours. `man 5 crontab` will show you how to set it, or you culd use the full path to `play` in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# no need to set $PATH
/usr/bin/play $HOME/Media/Music/my_audio.mp3
```

You can explore the differences between `cron`'s execution environment and the GUI execution environment by executing `(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >some.file` in both (with different values for `some file`).

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help! I dug around online some more, and when I simulated the bash environment for Cron and then ran the test bash script, I got this error, which I think is the real problem: 'ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave'. Do you happen to know what is causing this?